# class with Button as parent has no attribute "tk"

Tags: python, class, inheritance, button, tkinter

I was recently writing some code in which i wanted to create another class with button as a parent (This is because I wanted a button that would have various methods that normal buttons do not), like so:

```
from tkinter import *
class some_class(Button):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        pass
    #i will put more here 
root = Tk()
button = some_class(root)
button.pack()
mainloop()
```

yet doing this gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'some_class' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

then, if i add keywords like `text = "hello"` i get the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

i am relatively new to classes so any help on why this is happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Button.__init__` in your class to create tkinter button.

```
from tkinter import *


class MyButton(Button): # CamelCase class name

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Button.__init__(self, parent)
        # or
        #Button.__init__(self, parent, text="hello")


root = Tk()

button = MyButton(root)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

if you need to use `text="hello"` or other arguments with your class
then use `*args, **kwargs`

```
from tkinter import *


class MyButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)


root = Tk()

button = MyButton(root, text='Hello World!')
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really helpful.